# Align two div's side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to place two  elements side by side as opposed to stacked.  I'm sure this a fairly simple fix but, being new to coding, I can't seem to figure it out.  Secondly, if you notice with the social icons, I can't seem to figure out why the "Twitter" icon will not acknowledge the link.  The other 3 do but, Twitter will not.  Incidentally, my content area is 950px wide and I would like this to span the entire area.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Del087/angk8v6z/

The CSS

```
div {
background-color: #080808;
width: 950px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
}
#social a:hover {background-color: transparent;opacity:0.7;
} 
#social img { -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#social img:hover { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

The HTML

```
<div><div><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/RTH%20Artwork/RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png" border="0" alt=" photo RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png"/></a></div>
```

Comment: make sure your HTML is formatted correctly on this page - it will help us help you.

Comment: the twitter icon has is missing the "a" part of the <a href>

Comment: right now, all of your divs have the same width, and as mentioned above, there are many errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks very much guys for your input.  The Twitter button seems to be working correctly now.   I appreciate.  Still not exactly sure where to go with the divs.  @leftside I apologize.  New to coding and to SO.  I'll get there.

Comment: @leftside I guess that is where I am running into problems and, I hope, this is a forum for learning what I am doing wrong.  When you say "all my divs have the same length" is that simply because I don't have a width designated?  If that's the case should I change the width to pixels or a %?  I'm not exactly sure what route to take.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: you haven't differentiated between your divs (using classes or id's), any div on your page is set to 950px, as per your first declaration block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>`s have `display: block;` by default, and they have a hard return after the object. If you want multiple `<div>`s next to eachother, you can set the `display` property to `inline-block`. This means that the `<div>`s can be positioned next to eachother.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ruben Rutten.  Pardon my naivety but, where exactly am I going to place this coding?

Comment: In the class definition of BOTH `<div>`s or inline `style="display: inline-block;"`

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks @Ruben Rutten.  Appreciate

Comment: I apologize for being a pain in the ^&# @Ruben Rutten.  I tried that and am getting no results.  Check my updated Fiddle, if you would please and make sure I did it correctly.  Thanks.  http://jsfiddle.net/Del087/angk8v6z/2/